# Chart fail to interpret dates for label values

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a range of dates which I want to use as the labels on a graph. However, when I attempt to choose it as axis labels it is not interpreted as dates, as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Can anyone explain what is going on here? The axis it is plotted to is a text axis, so subsequent cells with the same value shouldn't be am issue.

The source data is put in the data sheet by a macro looking roughly like this:

```
Sub settInnIGraf(ws As Worksheet, R As Range)
  Dim C As Range
  Dim kortsone As Range, langsone As Range
  Set kortsone = R.Offset(0, 4).Resize(R.Rows.Count, 8)

  If IsEmpty(R) Then
    R.Resize(1, 21).Formula = "=na()"
  Else
    For Each C In Union(kortsone, langsone)
      If (Not IsNumeric(C)) Or Len(C) <= 0 Then
        C.Formula = "=na()"
      End If
    Next C
  End If
  With ws.ChartObjects("Kortsone" & Right(ws.CodeName, 1)).Chart
    Call settInnISerie(.SeriesCollection("Toppsuging"), R, kortsone.Columns(2))
    Call settInnISerie(.SeriesCollection("Nedsuging"), R, kortsone.Columns(4))
    Call settInnISerie(.SeriesCollection("Opptak"), R, kortsone.Columns(6))
    Call settInnISerie(.SeriesCollection("Botnsuging"), R, kortsone.Columns(8))
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -30
    .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 10
    .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MinimumScale
    .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MaximumScale
  End With
End Sub

Sub settInnISerie(srs As Series, xverdier As Range, yverdier As Range)
  Dim C As Range
  Dim i As Long

  srs.XValues = xverdier
  srs.Values = yverdier
  i = 1

  If srs.HasDataLabels Then
    srs.DataLabels.Delete
  End If
  srs.ApplyDataLabels
  For Each C In yverdier.Offset(0, -1).Cells
    If Not IsError(C) And i <= srs.Points.Count Then
      srs.Points(i).DataLabel.Text = "=" & Replace(C.Address(external:=True), "[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]", "", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Next C
End Sub
```

Comment: "so subsequent cells with the same value shouldn't be am issue" - I don't think that you can get axis labels with the same value even if they're text.

Comment: Did you enter them into the cells as 26.09.2016, in which case Excel thinks they are text and plots each (including duplicates) as a separate category, or did you enter them as actual dates, and format them as dd.mm.yyyy?

Comment: @JonPeltier I added the code which puts the data in the worksheet to the question, as you can see it adds them as actual dates and then formats them as dd.mm.yyyy

Comment: Actually, I can't see... Are you sure you updated the code in your question?